# If $n^x\in\Bbb Z,$ for every $n\in\Bbb Z^+,$ then $x\in\Bbb Z$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory, real-numbers

> Let $x$ is a real number such that $n^x\in\Bbb Z,$ for every positive integer $n.$ Prove that $x$ is an integer.

I got that problem [here](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1114696_hard_problem) and it looks difficult, I tried writing $x$ as $\lfloor x\rfloor+\{x\}$ (where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ and $\{x\}$ are the floor and the fractional part of $x,$ respectively), then $$n^x=n^{\lfloor x\rfloor}n^{\{x\}}.$$ Since $n^{\lfloor x\rfloor}>0,$ then $$n^{x-\lfloor x\rfloor}=n^{\{x\}},$$ so that $n^{\{x\}}$ must be a rational number for every positive integer $n,$ but I don't know how to prove that $\{x\}$ must necessarily be $0$ ($0\leq\{x\}<1$).

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: Any irrational power will not resolve as a simple root, though I don't know if you would need to prove that for your class. It is pretty obvious, though. That leaves you with rational powers. If $n^{\frac1k}\in\mathbb{Z}$, what do you know of $(n+1)^{\frac1k}$? Do you know anything at all about it?

Comment: The Gelfond–Schneider theorem states "If $a$ and $b$ are algebraic numbers with $a \ne 0,1$ and $b$ irrational, then any value of $a^b$ is a transcendental number.$

Comment: @TerraHyde How do you show it if the power is irrational?  For example $2^x = 3$ if $x = \log_2 3$, and $x$ is definitely irrational.

Comment: Now that I am thinking about it, I am not sure. The same rule applies to the irrationals as to the rationals about $n+1$, but I am not sure how to show it. Hmm.

Comment: For the case when $x = p/q$ is rational, you can just use $n=2$.  Because if $2^{p/q} = m \in \mathbb N$, then $2^p = m^q$.  Therefore $m$ must be a power of $2$ (because each integer has a unique prime factorization), and you quickly conclude $q | p$.

Comment: Of course, when $x$ is algebraic, the proof is "easy" (btw thank you for the link @StevenGregory), but what happens when $x$ is trascendental?, can we give an integer $m>0$ such that $m^x$ is not an integer?

Comment: @CarlosIsraelJrl. I don't know. I tried to think of an argument by contrapositive or contradiction but failed. I figured I could at least point out the reference and see if it helped someone smarter than I am.